# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure in account confirmation in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email

I was trying to implement email verification but when I enter this particular code at Startup.cs in ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) and try to run my program there's HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure. But if I comment out that code it works. How do I solve this issue?

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        });
```

Supposedly that code prevents new users from posting any data to the web site before they have a confirmed email.

Comment: Try to put break point in your startup.cs and run debug to see if there any exception

Comment: I ran through it, there wasn't any error, it just ran until CreateWebHostBuilder in program.cs then the error appears

Comment: ok nvm solved it thanks!

Comment: Can you post the answer so anyone will have same issue like can solve it. Thanks

Comment: I just needed to change it to services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>